# Creating a method which serves as a macro

Tags: c#, macros

Ok I'm not sure how to explain this, but take a look at this:

```
string fornavn = borgerXML.GetElementsByTagName("Fornavne")[id].InnerXml
```

Say I have 4 of these strings, which are getting different elements from the XML file.
On every single one of these, I want to do the following:

```
            .Replace("Ã¦", "æ")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Æ")
            .Replace("Ã¸", "ø")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Ø")
            .Replace("Ã¥", "å")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Å");
```

If I could store these 6 lines of code as a method or something, I'd only have to paste that method for every one of those 4 string elements, instead of pasting 4 times 6 lines of code.

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered reading the file with the right encoding instead of handling mangled characters from reading the file with the wrong encoding? Try specifying the UTF-8 encoding when reading the file.

Comment: Yes, I asked my teacher weeks ago but he didn't know how.
Is this possible?

But I'd also like to know the answer to this question as well, as it would be really handy.

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the xml, basically where `borgerXML` got the value from?

Comment: Also, can you post the very first line of the xml file in question?

Comment: borgerXML.Load(path + "//borgerliste.xml");

Comment: What is `path`? If this is from the web, judging by the double slashes, then it seems the file has been incorrectly encoded on the server, or the file is specifying the wrong encoding for the file. To be clear, this is *not* a problem you should handle with calls to `Replace`, you should *definitely* fix the problem by handling the encoding.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: It's not a server, it's a path I specify through a textbox, so other people can choose where they put the borgerlisten.xml file.
So it's a local path.

Comment: That is the wrong encoding. Those characters are from UTF-8 encoding, so basically the file has been produced with the wrong encoding. I would talk to the person that made the file. If you can't fix the server version of the file / production of the file, we can fix that though, but it involves a few more lines of code.

Comment: I produced the file. What's the correct encoding? This is the encoding my teacher recommended.

Comment: How did you write the file to disk in the first place? Because the encoding you've specified in the xml file does not match the actual encoding used, which looks like UTF-8.

Comment: It's just a remote file. It can be anywhere you want it to be, and have any kind of encoding. It just needs:
1 BorgerListe element containing
Atleast 1 Borger with
    1 Fornavne
    1 Efternavn
    1 CPR-Nummer
    1 ID

I get it now, I fixed it to be UTF-8. It works now, thanks

Comment: If you fixed it to be UTF-8, then you should remove the calls to `Replace`. Those are incorrect in any version of this problem.

Comment: I removed any Replace calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here is that the file, which according to your comment, specifies that it is encoded using the iso-8859-1 encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

does not in fact match that encoding, try this with [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    string wrong = "Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥";
    var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(wrong);
    string correct = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    correct.Dump();
}
```

This will output:

```
æ ø å
```

(note that I only used every second letter as the characters you've posted in the question are not an exact match to how they are actually encoded).

To fix this, go back to the code that produces the file and ensure it actually uses `iso-8859-1` encoding when writing the file, instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Convert(string source)
{
return source.Replace("Ã¦", "æ")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Æ")
            .Replace("Ã¸", "ø")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Ø")
            .Replace("Ã¥", "å")
            .Replace("Ã?", "Å");
}
```

If I undestood you correctly.  For each string you want to "process" call

```
Convert(value);
```

Comment: This is what I asked for, so even though fixing the encoding is correct, this is still what I asked for.
So I'll accept this answer for future reference, but I'll try fixing the encoding though.

Comment: At least fix the errors in the code, such as a missing `{`, although this answers your question (the one you asked) it is the wrong solution to your actual problem (wrong encoding used for xml file).

Comment: The other problem is to use the actual UTF8-bytes directly in the string. It may work now, but a roundtrip through a version control system or any other system that treats the file as pure text might mess up these characters. They should (if this is the correct way to go) be written as escaped code points instead. Again, this is the wrong solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I borrow a bit from here [Regex Replace - Multiple Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946997/regex-replace-multiple-characters) (actually you would have found this yourself with the search function) to make it a more generic solution which you can use for more or less characters:

1. define a function that can substitute dynamically:

   ```
   string MultiReplace(string original, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
   {
      //initialize result with original in case no replacements have been requested
      string result = original;

      foreach (var r in replacements)
      {
         result = result.Replace(r.Key, r.Value);
      }

      return result;
   }
   ```
2. Define a multi-use variable to save overhead of creating it every time you need:

   ```
   //You can create & initialize a dictionary variable like this:
   var charmap = new Dictionary<string, string> 
   { 
      { "Ã¦", "æ" }, 
      { "Ã?", "Æ" },
      { "Ã¸", "ø" },
      { "Ã?", "Ø" },
      { "Ã¥", "å" },
      { "Ã?", "Å" },
   };
   ```
3. Call this function with your specific task:

   ```
   var a = MultiReplace(fornavn, charmap);
   ```

In general it should be possible to fix this on the XML level though.

BR Florian